# How to get username logged into shiny app hosted on shinyapps.io

Tags: shiny, shinyapps

I am working on a shiny app where I am using bookmarks. So when host this app on shinyapps.io I am dont want other users to see the bookmarks which I did using my user login. I tried using `User = Sys.getenv("LOGNAME"))` but it always returns the username as Shiny.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you mean that you're using the shinyapps authentication, where users have to log in through shinyapps.io in order to see your app, then you can get the user's name using `session$user` on the server side.

Make sure that your server function is defined as `function(input, output, session)` rather than just `function(input, output)`

Comment: I did add that session. But I get this error `Error bookmarking state: column or argument 5 is NULL`

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue. Perhaps try to isolate the problem (get it to reproduce with as little code as possible) and post another question

Comment: My bad. Had to set the application to private . Then it works

Comment: I will add a second issue in that as a seperate question